# Amount rounding up when replacing comma to dot

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just realized that some amounts in my calcutations did not match with original ones (in excel - before I have imported it).

Brazilian amounts usually shows comma as a decimal identifier, however I kept my SQL Server as standard English that not recognizes it.

The workaround found was replace comma to dot but SQL Server is automatically rounding it up. See below example:

```
select vlr_contab_item vl1, replace(vlr_contab_item,',','.') vl2
--------------------
vl1       |   vl2
--------------------
40783,29  | 40783.3
--------------------
```

How to NOT round up amounts after replacing?

Comment: What is the datatype of column `vl1`? Do you see that the output for `vl2` gives you comma as well?

Comment: vlr_contab_item (vl1) type is float.

Comment: Never use float, it is an inexact datatype and it will round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @amount AS MONEY

SET @amount = 1200.5566

SELECT FORMAT(@amount, 'N', 'en-us') AS 'Number Format'
            ,FORMAT(@amount, 'G', 'en-us') AS 'General Format'
            ,FORMAT(@amount, 'C', 'en-us') AS 'Currency Format'
            ,FORMAT(@amount, 'C3', 'en-us') AS 'Currency Format'
            ,FORMAT(@amount ,'F', 'de-DE')   AS 'Currency Format'
```

[FORMAT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)

[Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Comment: It works! That is really helpful! 
Thank you so much!